# spring @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, exception, annotations

all,
my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search")
@ResponseBody
public CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>> search(
        @RequestParam("location") Location location) {
    CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>> restResponse = new CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>>();
    restResponse.setBody(new ArrayList<String>());
    Long a = Long.valueOf("aaaa");
    try {
        for (PublicCemetery cemetery : cemeteryDao.findByLocation(location)) {
            restResponse.getBody().add(cemetery.getNameCn());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            throw new SQLException();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    restResponse.setSuccess(true);
    return restResponse;
}
```

my execption handle method in a same controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class, SQLException.class,
        IllegalArgumentException.class, NumberFormatException.class })
@ResponseBody
public CemeteryRestResponse<String> exceptionHandler(Exception e,
        SQLException e2, IllegalArgumentException e3,
        NumberFormatException e4) {
    CemeteryRestResponse<String> restResponse = new CemeteryRestResponse<String>();
    restResponse.setFailureMessageCn("data base exception");

    restResponse.setSuccess(false);
    return restResponse;
}
```

when search method trhow SQLException and NumberFormatException @ExceptionHandler can not handle.
Thanks!

Comment: you are not throwing an exception from the method, all methods are handled using `try..catch` methods

Answer (score 0):

You catch `Exception` ( ALL exceptions), and then throw a new `SQLException`. You then immediately catch that SQLException and print its stacktrace. The search method will **NEVER** throw any exception.

Remove the try-catch around

```
throw new SQLException();
```

and it should work. But please reconsider your exception handling (don't catch ALL exceptions and then throw an exception of another type).

Answer (score 0):

There are not exception thrown from the request handler method, you are handling all the exceptions yourself.

The exception handler comes into effect only if the request handler throws an exception back to the spring framework.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search")
@ResponseBody
public CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>> search(
        @RequestParam("location") Location location) throws Exception{
    CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>> restResponse = new CemeteryRestResponse<List<String>>();
    restResponse.setBody(new ArrayList<String>());
    Long a = Long.valueOf("aaaa");
    for (PublicCemetery cemetery : cemeteryDao.findByLocation(location)) {
        restResponse.getBody().add(cemetery.getNameCn());
    }
    restResponse.setSuccess(true);
    return restResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your reply.
but fllow your reply it still can not handle.
if need xml config?